# performance monitoring tools for multi-tenant web application

Tags: java, multi-tenant, performance

We have a need to monitor performance of our java web app. We are looking for some tolls which can help us with this task. The major difficulty is that we are SaaS provider with multi-tenant server architecture with hundreds of customers running on the same hardware. So far we tried commercial products like DynaTrace and Coradinat but unfortunately they don't get the job done so far.  What we need is a simple report which would tell us if we had performance problems on each customer site in a specified period of time. Mostly it will be response time per customer but also we will need some more specifics based on the URLs.

please let me know if someone had any experience with setting up such monitoring.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "performance problems"?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not talking about performance problems here. Our problems are in performance monitoring. We want to have a complete solution which would tell us if all our sites are preforming well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [stagemonitor](http://www.stagemonitor.org/). It is an open source java web application performance monitoring library capable of multi-tenancy. It captures response time metrics, JVM metrics, request details and more. The overhead is very low. It uses the great timeseries database graphite that automatically downsamples historical datapoints which leads to a low storage overhead.

Here is a screenshot. You can find more on the [project site](http://www.stagemonitor.org/).
[image]

Note: I am the developer of stagemonitor

Comment: I installed it successfully but I don't know how to run it.

Comment: Did you follow the [installation guide](https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor/wiki/Installation)?

Answer (score 0):

HypericHQ is nice for this because, being written in Java itself, it integrates quite nicely with all the MBean properties already exposed on your APP server.  You can set up administrator alerts/charts based on JVM properties/app server MBean properties that most non-Java tools can't get at.

On the downside, it does like to run a relatively heavy (as these things go) agent on your server.

-I am not in any way affiliated with Hyperic Inc ;)